# undefined method `each' for "MySQL. Versions 5.0+ are recommended.":String in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

cloned the application from my friend I am getting this error, but in his machine working fine(same os), and deleted the database and trying to recreate but same issue.

mysql version: 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

my database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: timeline_sheet
test:
  <<: *default
  database: timeline_sheet_test
```

here is my gem file

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.7'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.13', '< 0.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'simple_form'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.1.1'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'prawn'
gem 'pdfkit', '0.5.0'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'passenger', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.30'
gem 'simple_format'
gem 'webrick', '~> 1.3.1'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

application trace:

```
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   active_record/base
```

Framework trace:

```
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:150:in `resolve_all'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:69:in `resolve'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/core.rb:46:in `configurations='
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/base.rb:315:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
activesupport (4.2.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `call'
```

[image]

Comment: The error is elsewhere, not in the code you posted.

Comment: JFYI, the stacktrace of an exception is as important as its message. Don't omit it (and learn to interpret it)

Comment: what is the version of MYSQL installed in system ?

Comment: mysql version 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 @SatishakumarAwati

Comment: Check the Gemfile.lock file of your friend for mysql2 rubygem version and try to install same version of gem on your machine. If you install correct version of mysql 2, it should work.